# AWS Lambda Python - How to import modules from local files to app.py

Tags: python

This is a simple SAM-template based deploy with a Docker container. Filesystem structure:

```
src/app.py
    mymodule.py
```

In app.py:

```
from .mymodule import myfunction
```

Result (on invoke):

```
Unable to import module 'app': attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Removing the dot results in:

```
Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'mymodule'
```

Adding the local directory to path does not help either:

```
import os, sys
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(currentdir)
```

Now I guess this appears to be due to the limitations described in the great answer from [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?rq=1)

i.e. app.py is being run as a script, not a module, and **scripts cannot import relatively**

The workarounds in the above answer both require changing some way the Lambda function is built and/or invoked - how to do this is the question?

Comment: Please try `from mymodule import ...` **without dot** before mymodule. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: It then fails with "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'mymodule'". Have also tried all the sys.path.append() ideas in that answer without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `__init__.py` file to your src folder (same level as ur app.py)

Or if you are using container, make sure your Dockerfile copies everything and not just app.py

Comment: What can I say. It was the Dockerfile. Thanks for taking the time!